# Disable printing of IO results in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghci

When running `IO` actions in GHCi prompt it automatically runs the action and shows result, this is nice, but not for students trying to understand difference between `IO` and non-`IO`. Is there a way to change configuration of GHCi so that it runs the action, but shows something like `<<IO Int action>>` instead? Something more like result for ST actions (but action should be performed):

now it does:

```
> return 1 :: IO Int
1
> return 1 :: ST s Int
<<ST action>>
```

i would like:

```
> return 1 :: IO Int
<<IO Int action>>
> putStrLn "bla"
bla
<<IO () action>>
```

**Edit**:

1. I just found that `IO` is probably the only thing handled specially by GHCi, `ST` actually has instance for `Show (ST s a)` which returns `"<<ST action>>"`. So maybe if I could disable this special treatment of `IO` it would be sufficient.
2. As for allowed code changes: manually changing evaluated expression is not an option. Change in libraries might be, but I would prefer not to do that (I considered creating wrapped `IO` type, but then interpreter will not run the action). If GHCi could automatically wrap `IO` actions somehow, that would be an option.

Comment: Are code changes acceptable? You could wrap the IO value that you have with another one that first executes the value and then prints something that you like.

Comment: usr: Not of the expression to-be-evaluated, see my edits of the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question. The only thing I can come up with is writing some kind of custom prelude module that exports a type called `IO`, but which isn't "the" I/O type that GHCi is special-casing.

Of course, this is no help at all unless the student remembers to import this rather than the real prelude. I suppose you could write that into the GHCi config file, but... well, it's certainly not perfect.

The only other way I can think of is to use the GHC-API to basically reimplement GHCi yourself. But that sounds like *waaaay* too much work...